# Touchpad and Trackpoint not working after Windows 10 64 bit January 2017 Update

Tags: windows-update, touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

I have a Thinkpad X120e, and the touchpad and trackpoint are acting strange.

Often after booting Windows, the touchpad and trackpoint will not work.  Other times it will, as long as it is not after the laptop has awoken from sleep.

This started happening a few days after Windows 10 January 2017 update. From my examination, I think the update was not the cause, because the touchpad and trackpoint do not work in Ubuntu either.

I use SSD, and disabled hibernation, but it still does not startup fast.

Here is what I have tried:

- I try to check the BIOS, and confirm the menu in BIOS to enable/disable touchpad and trackpoint is enabled.  However, the option is greyed out.
- I already tried to uninstall, update/downgrade the device driver using Lenovo, and using the generic driver from Synaptics.
- I already tried to revert the version of BIOS as well.

I read in Lenovo forum this can happen because the touchpad is in flash programming mode. To fix the problem, it need flashing firmware program from Lenovo (unfortunately not available for may laptop).

I tried seeking an answer from the [forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-13-E-and/Touchpad-permanently-not-working-after-resuming-from-suspend/td-p/878373), but there are so many responses already, my question got buried.

My questions,

1. How can both pieces of hardware break at the same? The touchpad and trackpoint are separate devices, with separate cables to the motherboard? Is it because of a controller chip malfunction in the mother board?
2. Can Windows 10 update cause this?
3. Please suggest what must I do to solve the problem, or any work around? (I am using Unified Remote app in my android phone and NeatMouse as mouse for on "lap" work now)

Also, I know my laptop isn't supported by Windows 10, and gets rather hot (~90 degrees Celsius).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, [after also posting on Ask Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884088/grub-bootloader-cause-touchpad-and-trackpoint-not-working/884686#884686)

The solution/workaround is to edit the grub file or repeat put computer to sleep until the touchpad/trackpoint get detected.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with a Lenovo X201. 
Removing the device driver with the subsequent reboot solved the problems (stutter and non-responsive touchpad). 
The touchpad works surprisingly smooth now, similar to a MacBook Air, even though it's much smaller. It even scrolls like an Apple, but that's something you could alter.
In  the bottom Windows "mouse settings" page you find "extra mouse options" and in the last tab of this "mouse properties screen" called "UltraNav" you can finetune many functions.